# dynamic cursors in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, cursor

```
 create procedure change_fid()

 begin
 declare t_flag integer default 0;
 declare t_fid varchar(5) default "";
 declare t_fname varchar(20) default "";
 declare t_source_code varchar(5) default "";
 declare t_destination_code varchar(5) default "";
 declare t_journey_hours decimal(2,0) default 0;

 declare change_fid_cursor cursor for
 select * from flight_temp;
 declare continue handler for not found set t_flag=1;

 begin
 drop table if exists flight_temp;
 create temporary table flight_temp (ta_fid varchar(5),ta_fname varchar(20),ta_source_code varchar(5),ta_destination_code varchar(5),ta_journey_hours decimal(2,0));
 select * into flight_temp from flight;
 update flight_temp set fid='FSA09' where fid='FSA08';
 open change_fid_cursor;
 looper : loop
 fetch change_fid_cursor into t_fid,t_fname,t_source_code,t_destination_code,t_journey_hours;
 if t_flag=1then leave looper;
 end if;
 select t_fid,t_fname,t_source_code,t_destination_code,t_journey_hours;
 end loop looper;
 close change_fid_cursor;
 end //
```

i am getting undeclared variable flight_temp. i even created a table flight_temp. still i am getting the same error.
i am trying dynamic cursors in mysql.

```
  ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: flight_temp
```

what am i doing wrong. i am new to cursors please guide me. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is that MySQL doesn't support [`SELECT INTO table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) syntax.

But MySQL supports [`INTO variable`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html) clause. That's why it treats `flight_temp` as a variable name.

You should use [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) syntax instead.

*That being said it looks like you don't need a cursor at all. If you can explain in plain words what you're trying to achieve you most likely can get help with that too.*

Comment: thank you, sir, i am trying to create a dynamic cursor to change the fid . i read some where that in mysql dynamic cursors can be implemented using temporary tables or views. please suggest me a right resource for implementing dynamic cursor and key set driven cursor in mysql.